# Insert function for a sorted linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

I wrote a program that gets some value and puts it in a sorted linked list.
The problem is that after entering the first value
the program stops
and it doesn't even run the insert function

I know the problem is in passing argument to the insert function
But I don't know how to fix it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct record{
    int data;
    struct record *nextptr;
};

void insert (struct record *ptr,int value);
void printList(struct record *ptr);

int main() {
    struct record *headptr = NULL;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        int data;
        printf("Enter your value");
        scanf("%d", &data);
        insert(headptr, data);
    }
    printList(headptr);


    return 0;
}

void insert (struct record *ptr,int value){
    printf("WE ARE IN THE INSERT FUNCTION");
    struct record *newptr = (struct record *) malloc(sizeof(struct record));
    newptr->data=value;
    newptr->nextptr=NULL;
    struct record *curptr;
    curptr=ptr;

    while(value >= (curptr->data)){
        curptr=curptr->nextptr;
    }
    if (curptr==NULL){
        ptr=newptr;
    }
    else{
        newptr->nextptr=curptr;
    }

}

void printList(struct record *ptr){
    while((*ptr).nextptr != NULL){
        printf("%d", ptr->data);
        ptr=ptr->nextptr;
    }
}
```

Result:

```
/Users/Danial/CLionProjects/Example/cmake-build-debug/Example
Enter your value3

Process finished with exit code 11
```

Comment: The problem is you are passing a pointer to your insert function, any changes made to the pointer inside the function will not make it out of the function, in order to do this you need to pass a pointer to the pointer **, then inside the function use (*).

Comment: what you are doing is the equivalent of this : `int foo(int n) { n = 1; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two big problems with `insert`. First you pass `ptr` as a pointer `struct record`. When that happens, your `insert` function receives a *copy-of-the-pointer* that points to the same location in memory, but has a distinct address itself, very different from the pointer passed from `main()`. What this means is not matter what you do to the copy of the pointer in `insert`, those changes will never be seen back in `main()` because you are operating on a copy and not otherwise returning a value. To cure that issue make your parameter `struct record **` and pass the address of the pointer from `main()`.

The next biggest problem you have in `insert` is you fail to check whether `curptr` is `NULL` (as it will be on the first call to `insert`) before you begin dereferencing `curptr` -- likely leading to a segfault or other run of the mill Undefined Behavior.

When creating a linked list, you have two distinct test conditions you must handle:

1. Am I inserting the first node? (if so, just assign `*ptr = newptr); and
2. all other insertions will require you to iterate to find the proper 2-nodes to insert your data between based on the `value` of the `data`.

You can handle both cases simply:

```
    rec_t *curptr = *ptr,
        *newptr = malloc (sizeof *newptr);
    if (!newptr) {
        perror ("malloc-newptr");
        return;
    }

    newptr->data = value;
    newptr->nextptr = NULL;

    if (curptr == NULL) {       /* handle new-list case and return */
        *ptr = newptr;
        return;
    }

    if (value < curptr->data) {     /* handle new 1st node */
        newptr->nextptr = curptr;
        *ptr = newptr;
        return;
    }

    /* iterate with curptr until value > curptr->nextptr->data */
    while (curptr->nextptr != NULL && value > curptr->nextptr->data)
        curptr = curptr->nextptr;

    newptr->nextptr = curptr->nextptr;      /* wire new node to next node */
    curptr->nextptr = newptr;               /* wire current to new node */
```

In any program you write that allocates memory, you must preserve a pointer to the start of each block allocated so it can be freed when that memory is no longer needed. You will generally want to write a `listfree` function to handle that for you. You could write something simple like the following:

```
void freelist (rec_t *head)
{
    while (head) {
        rec_t *victim = head;
        head = head->nextptr;
        free (victim);
    }
}
```

(**note:** how the node to free is saved in a temporary pointer `victim` before the list is advanced to the next node).

Putting it altogether, you could do something like the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct record {
    int data;
    struct record *nextptr;
} rec_t;

void insert (rec_t **ptr, int value);
void printList (rec_t *ptr);
void freelist (rec_t *head);

int main (void) {
    rec_t *headptr = NULL;

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        int data;
        printf("Enter your value: ");
        scanf("%d", &data);
        insert (&headptr, data);
    }
    printList(headptr);
    freelist (headptr);

    return 0;
}

void insert (rec_t **ptr, int value) 
{
    if ( ptr == NULL ) {
        return;  
    } 

    rec_t *curptr = *ptr,
        *newptr = malloc (sizeof *newptr);  /* don't cast the return */
    if (!newptr) {
        perror ("malloc-newptr");
        return;
    }

    newptr->data = value;
    newptr->nextptr = NULL;

    if (curptr == NULL) {       /* handle new-list case and return */
        *ptr = newptr;
        return;
    }

    if (value < curptr->data) {     /* handle new 1st node */
        newptr->nextptr = curptr;
        *ptr = newptr;
        return;
    }

    /* iterate with curptr until value > curptr->nextptr->data */
    while (curptr->nextptr != NULL && value > curptr->nextptr->data)
        curptr = curptr->nextptr;

    newptr->nextptr = curptr->nextptr;      /* wire new node to next node */
    curptr->nextptr = newptr;               /* wire current to new node */
}

void printList(struct record *ptr)
{
    while (ptr != NULL) {
        printf(" %d", ptr->data);
        ptr = ptr->nextptr;
    }
    putchar ('\n');
}

void freelist (rec_t *head)
{
    while (head) {
        rec_t *victim = head;
        head = head->nextptr;
        free (victim);
    }
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/lltcmpl
Enter your value: 1
Enter your value: 8
Enter your value: 5
Enter your value: 7
 1 5 7 8

$ ./bin/lltcmpl
Enter your value: 2
Enter your value: 1
Enter your value: 4
Enter your value: 3
 1 2 3 4
```

Look things over and let me know if you have questions.

Comment: This is wrong. Try `2 1 3 4` as your inputs, output should be `1 2 3 4` but is `2 1 3 4`

Comment: adding `if (curptr == *ptr && curptr->data > newptr->data) {
     newptr->nextptr = curptr;               
  *ptr = newptr;
  return; 
 }` before `while` in `insert` function would fix it.

Comment: My apologies, I omitted the check on the 1st node. Updated.

Answer (score 1):

Here you declare `headptr` and set it to `NULL`:

```
struct record *headptr = NULL;
```

Then you pass it to `insert`:

```
insert(headptr, data);
```

So, `ptr` in `insert` is `NULL`:

```
void insert(struct record *ptr, int value)
```

You then set `curptr = ptr;`, so `curptr` is `NULL`. It then crashes on this line:

```
while (value >= (curptr->data)) {
```

Because you're trying to access memory pointed at by `curptr`, which is `NULL` at that point.

My guess is that you wanted to allocate memory for `headptr` before passing it to `insert`. Or handle the case of the pointer being `NULL` in `insert`.

Answer (score 1):

If you pass a pointer to a function then whilst you can change the content of what the pointer points to you cannot modify the pointer, in order to achieve this you have to pass a pointer to the pointer:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct record{
    int data;
    struct record *nextptr;
};

void insert (struct record** ptr, int value);
void printList(struct record *ptr);

int main() {
    struct record *headptr = NULL;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        int data;
        printf("Enter your value");
        scanf("%d", &data);
        insert(&headptr, data);
    }
    printList(headptr);
    return 0;
}

void insert (struct record** ptr, int value) {
    if ( ptr == NULL ) {
    //Do nothing ptr is invalid
        return;  
    } 
    printf("WE ARE IN THE INSERT FUNCTION");
    struct record* curptr = *ptr
                ,* newptr = (struct record *) malloc(sizeof(struct record));
    newptr->data = value;
    //Check curptr isn't NULL
    while(curptr != NULL && value >= (curptr->data)){
        curptr = curptr->nextptr;
    }
    if (curptr == NULL) {
        newptr->nextptr = NULL;
        *ptr = newptr;
    } else {
        newptr->nextptr = curptr;
    }
}

void printList(struct record *ptr){
    while(ptr->nextptr != NULL) {
        printf("%d", ptr->data);
        ptr = ptr->nextptr;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are correct, but it may be a bit terse for the new C programmer, e.g. "*...in order to achieve this you have to pass a pointer to the pointer*" -- which allows passing the actual address of the original pointer in the calling function into the called function so that any changes made to the original pointer address are reflected in the calling function after the called function returns. If both a `head` and (`tail` pointer to the last node) are kept, you can avoid iterating to find the last node for insert.

Comment: You also have problems in insert. In order to do an "in order append", you would need to check `value >= curptr->nextptr->data` in order to properly bracket the 2-nodes between which the new-node will be inserted.

Answer (score 1):

First, use `setbuf(stdout, NULL);` if you want your prints to flush before your program terminates unexpectedly.

Second, as others have mentioned, you're accessing a `NULL` pointer element in `while (value >= (curptr->data))` which causes the crash.

Third, your `insert` and `print` logic is wrong as well.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct record{
    int data;
    struct record *nextptr;
};

void insert (struct record **ptr,int value);
void printList(struct record *ptr);

int main() {
    setbuf(stdout, NULL);
    struct record *headptr = NULL;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        int data;
        printf("Enter your value");
        scanf("%d", &data);
        insert(&headptr, data);
    }
    printList(headptr);


    return 0;
}
void insert (struct record **head,int value){
    printf("WE ARE IN THE INSERT FUNCTION");
    struct record *newptr = (struct record *) malloc(sizeof(struct record));
    newptr->data=value;
    newptr->nextptr=NULL;
    struct record *curptr=*head;
    struct record *prevcurptr=NULL;

    while(curptr!=NULL && value >= (curptr->data)){
        prevcurptr=curptr;
        curptr=curptr->nextptr;
    }
    if (curptr==NULL){
        if (prevcurptr==NULL) {         
            *head=newptr;
        } else {
            newptr->nextptr=prevcurptr->nextptr;
            prevcurptr->nextptr=newptr;
        }
    }
    else{
        newptr->nextptr=curptr;
        if (prevcurptr==NULL)       
            *head=newptr;
        else
            prevcurptr->nextptr=newptr;
    }

}
void printList(struct record *ptr){
    while(ptr != NULL){
        printf("\n %d", ptr->data);
        ptr=ptr->nextptr;
    }
}
```